# Magento 2 Ui Component admin form: Can i add timezone to datetimepicker?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have created a datetime picker in adminpanel form with ui component.

```
<field name="event_time">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Event Time</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">post</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">event_time</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>                        
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

My server has utc time wich is different than my local time. So if set my time to 18:00 i get 15:00 in front end.

Is there any option that i can set so that my time saves not with my store localtime but with server time?

Answer (score 0):

You can set timezone for server in

> Stores-> Configuration -> General -> Locale Options -> Timezone

Comment: thank you for your answer but i dont want to change my stores timezone, i just want to convert the time that saved by the datetimepicker to follow the servers time and also the time that datetimepicker displays in admin form to be converted to my local timezone